# php loop in attempt to add array values to an objects method / property

Tags: php, arrays, loops

If i hand code each array value like this:

```
$paymentDetailsType->setPaymentDetailsItem(
    array (
        'PaymentDetailsItem00' => $paymentDetailsItem,
        'PaymentDetailsItem01' => $paymentDetailsItem1,
    )
);
```

it works, however the number of array items can vary so i tried this with horrible results not sure what else to try

```
for ($i=0; $i<$_POST['cartcount']; $i++) {
    if ($i==0) {
        $paymentDetailsType->setPaymentDetailsItem(
            array (                     
                'PaymentDetailsItem00' => $paymentDetailsItem,
            )
        );
    } else {
        $paymentDetailsType =& $paymentDetailsType->setPaymentDetailsItem(
            array (
                'PaymentDetailsItem0'.$i.'' => ${'paymentDetailsItem'.$i},
            )
        );
    }
}
```

What I believe I am trying to do is add an array value to an object method.

Comment: Can you create an array first, and then pass that array as a parameter to your method?

Comment: @robonerd what a simple solution! yes that did the trick just created an array then add keys and values with a for loop then added the object property as the full array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$thenewarray = array (
    'PaymentDetailsItem00' => $paymentDetailsItem,
);

if ($_POST['cartcount']>1) {
    for ($i=1; $i<$_POST['cartcount']; $i++) {
        $thenewarray['PaymentDetailsItem0'.$i.''] = ${'paymentDetailsItem'.$i};
    }
    $i=0;
}

$paymentDetailsType->setPaymentDetailsItem($thenewarray);
```

created the array beforehand then loop through added the keys and values finally after the array has been completed add it to the object

Answer (score 0):

```
$paymentDetailsType =& $paymentDetailsType->setPaymentDetailsItem(
            array (
                'PaymentDetailsItem0'.$i.'' => ${'paymentDetailsItem'.$i},
            )
        );
```

This part won't work, because you can't expect two objects to be merged when using `=&`. When you want to add arrays, you can call [`array_merge()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). You could for example change your `paymentDetailsType` to this:

```
class paymentDetailsType
{
    private $_items = array();

    function addPaymentDetailsItem($items)
    {
        $_items = array_merge($_items, $items);
    }
}
```

Besides that, when you change `${'paymentDetailsItem'.$i}` to being an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), you can simply address the items as `$paymentDetailsItem[$i]` and simply use `$i` as the key.